# invert table column with css

Tags: html, css

```css
.market {
  width: 100%;
}

.market tbody tr {
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f2943;
  cursor: pointer;
}

table.market {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

table.market tr {
  transform: rotate(-180deg);
}
```

```html
<table class="market">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>6,53,500</td>
      <td>0.28368756</td>
      <td>74125.05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5,53,500</td>
      <td>0.28368756</td>
      <td>74125.05</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5,53,500</td>
      <td>0.28368756</td>
      <td>74125.05</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note: This working Fine but, when i use transform : rotate Table Row (tr) border removed or not working. I need first Column to last in table. I am trying to fix from many hours, tired now please help.

Comment: Please create also an example with the not working version and explain what you are trying to achieve. Am I right that you want to change the order of your columns? If so under, which conditions?

Answer (score 4):

```
direction: rtl;
```

This inverses a table with one line of CSS!

Comment: example? Not working for me...

Answer (score 1):

So you want to reverse the row ordering, right? Could you use [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout), or do you need to support older browsers? Here's a solution using flexbox:

```
.market{
  width: 100%;
}

.market tbody {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.market tbody tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  color: #555;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1f2943;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.market tbody td {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
```

And here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zqyr7n9m/17/)

Comment: i used but have to add display:flex; its conflict with my code